# <img> content: default value

Tags: javascript, html

I am new to HTML5 and javascript and I have a question.

I have the following HTML code

```
<img id='image_preview'/>";
<input type='file' name='fileUpl' id='fileUpl' onchange='doUpl();' accept='image/*'/>
```

So in short, there is a button, every time I click it, doUpl() is executed. It loads a picture and shows a preview of the picture into `<img ... >`

the js function is

```
function doUpl() {
        var file = document.getElementById('fileUpl').files[0];
         ...
        dataUrl = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg");
        document.getElementById('image_preview').src = dataUrl;  
        ...
```

I would like to have the input field pre-loaded with a default picture path (ex. c:\test.jpg) and the preview of test.jpg already shown when the page is loaded the first time. If the button is pressed the picture is updated.

At the moment, when I first load the html page there is no preview and the input path is empty.

Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks :)

edit: sorry for the confusion. the test img is of course on the server not on the client PC.

Comment: Neither `<img>` nor `<input>` need or use a closing slash.

Comment: Also it would be totally against security to auto preload pictures from client hard drive so I don't think that is supported

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I would like to have the input field pre-loaded with a default picture path (ex. c:\test.jpg)

You can do that using the `value` attribute. Something like this:

`<input type='file' name='fileUpl' id='fileUpl' onchange='doUpl();' accept='image/*' value='c:\test.jpg'/>`

> the preview of test.jpg already shown when the page is loaded the first time.

There are a couple ways you can do this. The basic one is to do like above, using the `src` attribute:

`<img id='image_preview' src='c:\test.jpg'/>"`

But, I think is better to do using javascript, because, if one day you need to change this standard image, you only change it on the `input` element.

```
 </body>
    <script>
    // self executing function here
    (function() {
       doUpl(); //this will execute when page is loaded.        
    })();
    </script>
```

*P.S. This is only possible if you have `c:\test.jpg` on your **server***

Comment: thank you very much. tomorrow I´ll try but probably will do the job :)

Comment: @Mr.Pad Ok. Any problem, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if there is something on the input and fake the img and fake the path but you cannot get a real image from the user hard drive because it's security

Answer (score -1):

If you are talking about preloading images from the client's filesystem, I'm afraid this is not possible due to obvious security reasons:

The specification of the [File API](https://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/) states that:

> (..) This specification also assumes that the primary user interaction is
>   with the  element of HTML forms [HTML], and that
>   all files that are being read by FileReader objects have first been
>   selected by the user (..)